# Zip process taking too long when using password for 700 GB file

Tags: c#, dotnetzip

I've used the code below without the password option for a 700 GB file and it ran pretty fast (about 4 hours). Trying the exact same with 7ZIP would take about 2 days. However, when I add the password option it just shows zero bytes for the zip file being created. Is there anything wrong with the code below (password specific)? Is there anyway the code below can run faster when a password is specified?

```
string password = "uG9GHi@4";

Console.WriteLine("txtFileInPath 991 :" + txtFileInPath);
Console.WriteLine("zipFileOutPath :" + zipFileOutPath);
Console.WriteLine("Password       :" + password);
Console.WriteLine("running        :" + DateTime.Now);

using (ZipFile zip = new ZipFile())
{                        
    zip.UseZip64WhenSaving = Zip64Option.Always;                
    zip.CompressionLevel = Ionic.Zlib.CompressionLevel.BestCompression;                
    //zip.Password = password;               
    Console.WriteLine("Before AddFile    :" + DateTime.Now);
    zip.AddFile(txtFileInPath, "").Password = password;
    Console.WriteLine("After AddFile    :" + DateTime.Now);

    Console.WriteLine("Before zip.Save    :" + DateTime.Now);
    zip.Save(zipFileOutPath);                
    Console.WriteLine("After zip.Save    :" + DateTime.Now);
}
Console.WriteLine("End              :" + DateTime.Now);
```

Comment: Encryption *does* take a lot of time. As for 7Zip, if you enable parallel processing it performs *much* faster, using all available cores. If DotNetZip doesn't allow parallel processing, you may have to buy the commercial version.

Comment: I believe that DotNetZip already does parallel processing (no code changes) needed. The encryption using DotNetZip without the password is really fast, however, when the password is added that's where it becomes really slow.

Comment: Any different if you use `zip.Encryption = EncryptionAlgorithm.WinZipAes256`?

Comment: I did try that and it was faster...but still not ideal.

Comment: Zipping a 700 GB file without password took ~ 5 hours (164 GB resulting file).

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Comment: Zipping a 700 GB file with password and using zip.Encryption = EncryptionAlgorithm.WinZipAes256 was running about 30 GB zipped data per 6 hours which means that it would take about 32 hours.

Comment: Have you tried using a larger `zip.BufferSize`?  The documentation suggests 65536*8 (512k) might be more efficient when dealing with zip entries larger than 1GB.